# How to match a pattern but a pattern on regex

Tags: php, regex, bash, pattern-matching

If I have a list of filename e.g.:

```
member_1235435.dat
member_1243533.txt
member_1_1_2015.txt
member_1_3_2015_rejected.dat
```

How can I match all within a pattern of member_{number}.extension except those with `_rejected`?

So far I have like this:

```
^Member_.*.*
```

I thought it will look like this, but it does not work.

```
^Member_.*(?!_rejected).*
```

I tried the first answer in comment

```
24646-MBPRS-Username:myapp Username$ ./src/myapp launcher:local ~/Desktop/myfilesdirectory /^member_(?:.(?!_rejected))*$/
-bash: !_rejected: event not found
```

I tried to escape ! sign, this is what I got

```
24646-MBPRS-Username:myapp Username$ ./src/myapp launcher:local ~/Desktop/myfilesdirectory /^member_(?:.(?\!_rejected))*$/
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

FYI, the pattern will go through command line argument

Comment: Are you using case insensitive modifier?

Comment: Yes. I am using insensitive modifier

Comment: `^member_(?:.(?!_rejected))*$` - https://regex101.com/r/cR9bF3/1

Comment: @JoshCrozier I tried run it, it failed: 24646-MBPRS-Username:myapp username$ ./src/myapp launcher:local ~/Desktop/myfilesdirectory /^member_(?:.(?!_rejected))*$/
Result --> -bash: !_rejected: event not found

Comment: In bash, filename patterns are not regexes. They are "globs". (Even where regexes are possible, such as inside `[[...]]`, lookahead assertions are not implemented. However, you can use extended globs.

Answer (score 1):

If the acceptable names have combinations of numbers and `_` after `member_` you can simply use following regex :

```
^member_[\d_]+\.\w+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer works. I've used this code to test:

```
<?php
$s = [
    'member_1235435.dat',
    'member_1243533.txt',
    'member_1_1_2015.txts',
    'mber_1_1_2015.txt',
    'member_1_3_2015_rejected.dat'
];

echo preg_match('/^member_[\d_]+\.\w+$/', $s[1]) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

In case you want to use a extension with 3 letters, use `'/^member_[\d_]+\.\w{3}$/'`.

Comment: it does not work, when I ran it on command line, it gave me -bash: !_rejected: event not found

Comment: Well, I'm trying this code from a index.php file, running from the Eclipse/PDT environment. Perhaps, bash is parsing some code as a command...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the discard technique by using a regex like this:

```
.*rejected(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB9cJ7/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using the ".ext" as the terminator after the numerical term.

```
$ grep -Eo 'member_[0-9_]+\.(.*)$' file

member_1235435.dat
member_1243533.txt
member_1_1_2015.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, filename patterns are not regexes. They are ["globs"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Even where regexes are possible, such as inside [[...]], lookahead assertions are not implemented.

However, you can use extended globs, as described in the bash guide linked above:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo member_!(*_rejected*).dat
member_1235435.dat
$ echo member_!(*_rejected*).*
member_1235435.dat
member_1243533.txt
member_1_1_2015.txt
```